# pygame.event.set_grab remains turned on after exception / crash and makes program "unkillable"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am creating a game with **pygame** and I am using **pygame.event.set_grab(True)** to keep cursor locked in the game window (it keeps all keyboard input in the window also), but when the program crashes (either because of syntax error or some other exception) the set_grab stays turned on and it is impossible to turn off the program afterwards. (fortunately I am using Linux so i can access console that overrides everything so i can turn it off manually)
I am wondering if it is possible to make some error handling which will turn it off (or kills the program) or if there is a better way to keep *just* mouse inputs in the window. (so it is possible to alt+f4)

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
size = (600, 700)
monitor=pygame.display.Info()  
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)#pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Meteor Galaxy 3")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pygame.event.set_grab(True) #this is turned on with the  initialization
#(doesnt have to be) of the game
```

When the game crashes it transforms into the usual black window with the exception you cant do anything.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
The full code:

```
#coding: utf-8
import pygame
import random

random.randint(0,2)
#TODO: 
#Vymyslieť systém na čakanie framov
#Upraviť zmenu rýchlosti hráčovho náboja
##Pygame init
pygame.init()
size = (600, 700)
possible_sizes=[[600,700],[900,1050],[1200,1400],[1800,2100]]  #ASI 1200,1400 obrázky a potom downscale?? (ak vôbec zmena rozlisenia..)
monitor=pygame.display.Info()  
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)#pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Meteor Galaxy 3")
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
pygame.event.set_grab(True)

#<VARIABLES>
##<COLORS>
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
##</COLORS>
##<IMAGES> #"../meteo_data/img/"
bg1=[pygame.image.load("../meteo_data/img/bg1.png"),700-5770,True]

#backgrounds.append([pygame.image.load("img/bg2.png"),[600,1924]])
#backgrounds.append([pygame.image.load("img/bg3.png"),[600,1924]])
img_crosshair=pygame.image.load("../meteo_data/img/crosshair.png").convert()
#Ships
img_player=pygame.image.load("../meteo_data/img/ships/player.png").convert()
img_enemy1=pygame.image.load("../meteo_data/img/ships/enemy1.png").convert()
#Bullets
img_b1=pygame.image.load("../meteo_data/img/bullets/bullet.png").convert() 


img_player.set_colorkey(BLACK)
img_enemy1.set_colorkey(BLACK)
img_crosshair.set_colorkey(BLACK)
##</IMAGES>

##<SOUNDS>

##</SOUNDS>

menu_game=1 #Nula pre menu , jedna pre hru?? , medzi nula a jedna ostatné??
esc_menu=False
fire=False
level=-1
level_ended=True
##                                                         def=0 def=0
##<BULLET TYPES> #[IMAGE,DAMAGE,SPEED,PENETRATION,relX,relY] /relX a relY vziať z relX a relY lode.
B_default=[img_b1,3,4,False,0,0]
##</BULLET TYPES>

##<SHIP TYPES> #[IMAGE,HEALTH,SPEED,RELOAD,X,Y,relX,relY,BULLET_TYPE] /relX a relY je pre bullet

##</SHIP TYPES>

##<LEVELS>
level1=[bg1]

master_level=[level1]
##</LEVELS>
#</VARIABLES>


#<FUNCTIONS>
##<SPRITES>
class bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self,bullet_type):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image=bullet_type[0]
      self.dmg=bullet_type[1]
      self.speed=bullet_type[2]
      self.penetration=bullet_type[3] ##Prestrelí viac ENIMÁKOV ? True/False
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.x=bullet_type[4] ##Vypočítať pri vystrelení (ship pos -/+ ship.bullet_x(y)) (pre každý typ lode zvlášť)
      self.rect.y=bullet_type[5]
      self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

class ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self,ship_type):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image=ship_type[0]
      self.hp=ship_type[1]
      self.speed=ship_type[2] ##0 Pre hráča
      self.reload=ship_type[3] ##Rýchlosť streľby (koľko framov čakať) 0 = každý frame bullet
      self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.x=ship_type[4]
      self.rect.y=ship_type[5]
      self.bullet_x=ship_type[6]
      self.bullet_y=ship_type[7]
      self.b_type=ship_type[8]
      self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
class barrier(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self,coord):
      pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
      self.image=pygame.Surface([700,40])
      self.image.fill(WHITE)
      self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
      self.rect.x=coord[0]
      self.rect.y=coord[1]

bullets=pygame.sprite.Group()
ships=pygame.sprite.Group()
barriers=pygame.sprite.Group()

player_b_type=B_default
player_b_type[2]=player_b_type[2]*(-1)
player=ship([img_player,100,0,10,279,650,15,3,player_b_type])  ##PLAYER SHIP
wait=player.reload
barrier_top=barrier([-50,-400])
barrier_bottom=barrier([-50,900])

barriers.add(barrier_top)
barriers.add(barrier_bottom)
##</SPRITES>


#</FUNCTIONS>

while not done:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         done = True
      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         if event.button==1:
            fire=True
      elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
         if event.button==1:
            fire=False
      elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key==pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            if not esc_menu:
               esc_menu=True
               pygame.event.set_grab(False)
            else:
               esc_menu=False
               pygame.event.set_grab(True)
   coord=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
   if menu_game==0:
      screen.fill(WHITE) #BG
   elif menu_game==1:
      #GAME LOGIC
      if level_ended:
          level=level+1
          bg1_y=master_level[level][0][1]
          level_ended=False
      bg1_y=bg1_y+2
      player.rect.x=coord[0]-20

      pygame.sprite.groupcollide(barriers,bullets,False,True)
      pygame.sprite.groupcollide(barriers,ships,False,True)
      if fire:
         if wait==0:
            bullet_modified=player.b_type
            bullet_modified[4]=player.rect.x+player.bullet_x
            bullet_modified[5]=player.rect.y+player.bullet_y
            b=bullet(bullet_modified)
            bullets.add(b)         
            wait=player.reload
         else:
            wait=wait-1
      #RENDERING
      screen.fill(BLACK)
      screen.blit(master_level[level][0][0],[0,bg1_y]) #BG
      screen.blit(player.image,player.rect)

      for naboj in bullets:
         screen.blit(naboj.image,naboj.rect)
         naboj.rect.y=naboj.rect.y+naboj.speed
      screen.blit(img_crosshair,[coord[0]-10,coord[1]-10])

   pygame.display.flip() #FRAMY
   clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()

#NOTES:
# Dlzka lvl sa urci vyskou bg (5760 px == 48 sec - 1. lvl)
#189 - 
#
```

Comment: Please post your code (a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: The code is not realy needed because it doesnt matter why it crashes but i will post something

Comment: we need to know how is your normal clean-up, so we can suggest how to redirect to it.

Comment: Ok i added whole code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem there is that if some exception happens in the middle of that code, `pygame.quit()` is never called.

All you have to do is to set a `try ... fynaly` block around your Pygame code, and put the `pygame.quit()` call on the finally block.

For that I suggest some reformatting which will also improve the modularity of your code, which is to enclose all that code you put on the module level inside a function.

So:

```
...

def main():
    done = False
    while not done:
        ...
        for naboj in bullets:
            ...
            screen.blit(img_crosshair,[coord[0]-10,coord[1]-10])

        pygame.display.flip() #FRAMY
        clock.tick(60)

try:
    main()
finally:
    pygame.quit()
```

In this way, any unhandled exception within the code run in `main` (or in any other function called from it), as well as well behaved main-loop termination, will immediately run the code within the `finally` block: Pygame is shut down, along with its event handling, and you get the error traceback on the terminal enabling you to fix the code.

**update** the `finally` hint is also essential  for anyone making a game with pygame that uses fullscreen, regardless of event_grab.

Comment: As an extra hint for improving your code, I'd suggest you to abuse functions - put the code above the mainloop in a `setup` function, put some of the verifying `if` blocks, like event handling an d `if fire` in separate functions - and try to get a feel of "prettier" code. You may need to use some (or a lot) of global variables to get started without much refactoring,  but even then you might appreciate the new look of your program.

Comment: Thanks I am going to use this. And thanks for the hint :D